# Codeigniter Javascript Reload issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have written an AJAX JS script - after the script is successful it reloads the page using:

```
location.reload();
```

however I'm having a few issues with the URL's in codeigniter for example a user will post data on some forms on my page to:

```
http://localhost/project/main/getusers
```

and after my ajax script has used reload() it refresh's the page to:

```
http://localhost/project/main/
```

rather than:

```
http://localhost/project/main/getusers
```

has anyone noticed this before or is there a way to grab the current url in JS to reload the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a function for getting the current url:
current_url(), see if it works.

Comment: No it doesnt having a whole host of issues - thinking of changin my functionality to just include a form without JS

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to post your ajax request code and potentially where it is called, but if you are using ajax, there is no need to reload the page...that's the entire point of using ajax. You should just get the result from your ajax request and use jquery to write it to the page after the request is complete.